# How to merge "static" observable with "dynamic" in rxjs 6?

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm writing chrome extension and decided to wrap everything into streams, mostly for training and take a look into rxjs.

So I’m stuck with such a problem. I have two streams, one stream is ***static*** *(don’t know how to correctly name it)* and one ***dynamic***.

A static stream is that one who emits value only when you subscribe to it (**getPath$**), it return value from a chrome storage. 
A dynamic (**message$**) stream is a stream which listening for events(messages).

So my goal is somehow to merge this two stream and every time when I’m receiving a message from **message$** get value from a **getPath$** and make some calculations based on two values.

```
type Handler = (
    message: any, 
    sender: any, 
    sendResponse: (response: any) => void
) => void; 

type Values  = string | string[];

const getValues = (values: Values) => (cb) => chrome.storage.local.get(values, cb) 
const getPathBinded = bindCallback(getValues('path')) 
const getPath$ = getPathBinded() 

const message$ = fromEventPattern( 
   (handler: Handler) => chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handler), 
   (handler: Handler) => chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(handler), 
   (message, sender, sendResponse) => ({ message, sender, sendResponse }) 
).pipe( 
    map(
       ({ message }) => message
    ) 
)
```

I found how to do this in such a way:

```
message$.pipe( 
    switchMap( 
        _ => getPath$, 
        (oV, iV) => {
            //doing some calculation
        } 
    ) 
 )
```

Or

```
combineLatest(
  message$,
  getPath$,
).pipe(
    map((a, b) => {
       //doing some calculation
    })
)
```

Seems like it's working, but it feels like I am doing wrong. Any suggestions or how to do it following best approaches? Also, please correct me in definitions.

**UPD**
Here the full [code: https://gist.github.com/](https://gist.github.com/dmfilipenko/afb4559d5be3cf02aa0d05888fe66330)
And the latest version which is work

```
const merged$ = message$.pipe(
   switchMap(sendedPath => combineLatest(
        path$,
        unit$
    ).pipe(
        map(([path, unit]) => [sendedPath, path, unit]))
    )
)
```

Comment: Well, if your approach is right or wrong depends on what you want to do...

Comment: Should `chrome.storage.local.get(values, cb)` be recalculated with every new message or it is fine to use the first for all messages?

Comment: @OlesSavluk it should recalculate every time with new message

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is

> to merge this two stream and every time when I’m receiving a message from
>   message$ get value from a getPath$ and make some calculations based on two values

it looks like the `switchMap` approach is the right one. `switchMap` in this case means: any time I receive a notification from `message$` I switch to the other Observable, in this case the one returned by invoking `getPath$`.

If you then want to do something with both values, then probably you can not afford to ignore the value notified by `message$`, which is what your code currently does, and you have to pipe a `map` into the result of `getPath$` so that you can create an object containing the 2 values notified by the 2 Observables and pass such object to the following calculation. The code should look like

```
message$.pipe( 
    switchMap( 
        message => getPath$.pipe(map(path => ({message, path}))), 
        map(({message, path}) => {
            //doing some calculation
        })
    ) 
 )
```

Comment: Yeap, I need to do something with both values. As I understand correct, `switchMap` is switching from one observable to another. This is not exactly what I want. I want that they simultaneously return some values and based on this values do some works.

Comment: What do you mean "simultaneously return some values"? I understand that `message$` emits when something happens, and any time it emits you want to call `getPath$` and do something with both values. This is what the code I suggest should do. By the way, I corrected a type. I forgot to add the `map` operator after `switchMap`.

Comment: thnx for the answer seems like it's my way. As I understand from the documentation, you can pass as a second parameter to switchMap resultSelector wich get access to the value of inner and outer, so second argument
```map()``` is redundant or I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What you name dynamic/static is similar to [Hot and Cold Observables](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339), but not exactly the same.

Your first approach with `switchMap` is mostly fine, except that you should recalculate it every time:

```
const combined$ = messages$.pipe(
  mergeMap(() => getPathBinded(), (message, path) => { ... })
)
```

I have also changed `switchMap` to `mergeMap`, otherwise, you may "lost" some of the messages, see [RxJS: Avoiding switchMap-Related Bugs](https://blog.angularindepth.com/switchmap-bugs-b6de69155524)

---

And also you may simplify your code a little bit:

```
const getStorage = bindCallback(chrome.storage.local.get); 
// use it as: const path$ = getStorage("path")

const message$ = fromEvent(chrome.runtime.onMessage);    
// should be enough, since you are only using default methods
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to correctly name this dynamic/static, passive/active, hot/cold.


I'll try to explain what I mean.
Dynamic or active – it's kind of observable which is working independently. For example, are listening to events forever if you don't unsubscribe it.  
Passive or static – it's only returning value when you need it (requesting it).
I'm totally confident this definition is wrong, but I don't know how to explain it right.